# Reuse JSDoc comment between TypeScript interfaces

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

Let's say I have the following interfaces:

```
interface Foo {
  /**
   * A date string in the format `yyyy-MM-dd`
   */
  archiveDate: string;
}

interface Bar {
  /**
   * A date string in the format `yyyy-MM-dd`
   */
  publishDate: string;
}
```

As you can see, the JSDoc descriptions are exactly the same between the two interfaces. Is there a way of sharing the descriptions between the two (and possibly many more) interfaces so I don't have to copy/paste the same description many times.

Comment: have you found a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

Arguably the JSDoc comment refers to the type string here, not the property. So you can define a type alias and put the doc comment there.

```
/**
 * A date string in the format `yyyy-MM-dd`
 */
type DateString = string;

interface Foo {
  archiveDate: DateString;
}

interface Bar {
  publishDate: DateString;
}
```

You can even encode the format as a string literal type:

```
type Digit = '0' | '1' | '2' | '3' // | ... ;
type DateString = `${Digit}${Digit}${Digit}${Digit}-${Digit}${Digit}-${Digit}${Digit}`;
```

(resolving the error `Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent.(2590)` when adding the remaining digits is left as an exercise for the reader)

Then you even get errors when you don't use the format:

```
const foo: Foo = {
  archiveDate: '2023-1-1'
}
```

```
Type '"2023-1-1"' is not assignable to type '"0000-00-00" | "0000-00-01" | "0000-00-02" | "0000-00-03" | "0000-00-10" | "0000-00-11" | "0000-00-12" | "0000-00-13" | "0000-00-20" | "0000-00-21" | "0000-00-22" | "0000-00-23" | ... 65523 more ... | "3333-33-33"'. Did you mean '"2023-01-01"'?(2820)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIglgczsKBeKByADBqAfTARlwIwCYTMBmXAelvygDoWoBuAKFElgENgIAZWAAnOADsEaKAAMAJAG94SYAF9Fy5OqWItG3WoC0+lds1GTenaZmcOEgSIBmvAMbQAYgHsvUBRygoXhFXAAs4ADcIGH4IAC4+AWExSU5VDntxRxd3KAAhYL8AqDAAVwAjABs4AGdQmIEEhqFRCQQ0jNcvcRqUJx8E7190f0DgsMjo2ITyLDIqQ0JFjA50oA)